# Why OEM RMAN backup jobs fail after changing the preferred credentials?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, rman, password, oracle-enterprise-manager

In an `Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production`, Running on Oracle Linux 6.5, we configured full RMAN backup schedule using OEM (`Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g Database Control Release 11.2.0.4.0`) to take full backup once a week, and incremental level 1 for the rest of the week. This setup went smoothly until we were forced by internal policy to change passwords.

We did change the host's credentials (`oracle` user and `root`) plus the main schema. `sys` and `system` were unchanged (yet), then I did update the preferred credentials in the OEM, but the next job failed!

Before retrying, I double checked that we chose to use the preferred passwords, and that I didn't misspelled when I typed them (I did `test` the preferred credentials, misspelled host, sysdba, and normal credentials and watched the errors for each, then entered them carefully and tested again and had a success), but the job failed again. I did change the credentials for the job so it use custom credentials and entered the new credentials manually, retried and failed again!

To get more sure, I created a new job, the same settings we chose for the old job, using the preferred credentials, and ran it immediately, and it succeeded! This made me sure that I didn't mess up the preferred credentials, but there's something in the old job that doesn't respond the way I expect it to do, which is to take the preferred credentials at runtime. It even didn't take the custom credentials when I manually specified it!

So what am I missing here? Is there any other step that I overlooked or forgot to do (or didn't know I should)? Is it the expected behavior and I should delete and recreate all the jobs whenever I change passwords?

EDIT:

OEM version (output of `emctl getversion`):

```
Enterprise Manager 11g DB Control Version 11.2.0.4.0
Enterprise Manager 10g Agent Version 10.2.0.4.0
```

Comment: Did you check the host (ssh) passwords as well as the database ones? Really pisses me off when "expert" security bods in corporations enforce password changes on service accounts. Utterly pointless.

Comment: yes, I did as well, checked them all.. It pisses me as well, and they know how to scare top managment to sign off their messed up policies!..

Comment: What version of OEM?

Comment: You should be using ssh with keys, not passwords, @Phil. Is it possible to configure Oracle to work in the same way?

Comment: @Phil edited to show the version...

Comment: Ideally you want to run the backups from cron. You use the dbsnmp account from the agent to connect grid, but that account does not have access to do the backups. So you maintain credentials within grid to connect as sys or whatever user you make the backup user. But if you schedule the backup job with cron as long as the Oracle account has access to cron and it can run the backup script the backups will work. What happens to your backups if Grid crashes? There are fewer dependencies for your backups when you use cron to schedule them.

Comment: Also make sure that your full backups are level 0 full backups, and if you have Enterprise make sure that you have a block change tracking file. I would not recommend incrementals with out one.

Comment: @Gandolf989 yes, currently researching changing to cron jobs, and yes I double checked that the full backups are marked as level zero (`Use as the base of an incremental backup strategy`)...